# unable to load ovf to virtualbox created using vmware vphrere export?

Tags: vmware, virtualbox, appliance

I am trying to load a VM that was created by someone else using VMware vSphere into virtualbox. I got these 3 files, the first one being an xml ovf file, the second one containing the SHA1 sums and the last one being a 3.2GB vmdk:

```
myVM.ovf
myVM.mf
myVM-disk1.vmdk
```

When I try `Import an Appliance` choosing the ovf file, I get this error:

```
Failed to import appliance /home/username/VirtualBox VMs/blah/blah/myVM.ovf.

&lt;vbox:Machine&gt; element in OVF contains a medium attachment for the disk image 58d8e82a-37a1-4c10-b3be-b53cdb213fbe but the OVF describes no such image.

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Appliance
Interface: IAppliance {3059cf9e-25c7-4f0b-9fa5-3c42e441670b}
```

I made sure the menu is pointing to the right vmdk file, but still there is something wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received a similar issue today when doing a simple export / import of a windows 7 vm running Oracle VM 4.3.1 on linux mint. I exported in OVF 2.0 and it generated an .ova file. I had nearly identical error message when importing the image. I am assuming the image was made with Oracle VM.

"Failed to import appliance /home/val/Desktop/win7.ova"... "the OVF describes no such image"

THE FIX: All I had to do was rename the .ova file to .ovf; you may have to change the .ovf extension to .ova as well. Also ensure you are the owner of the file (chown) and you have correct permissions(chmod). This worked for me it may work for you.

I found this fix here: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/9414

Answer (score 12):

At the Import dialog, try to uncheck USB controller and CD/DVD devices.

[image]

If that will help, You can enable them afterwards. In fact, You will need them to install Guest Additions later.

This helped for me, to install Microsoft prepared Virtual machines for different Internet Explorer tests from http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/